# Removing titlebar gap

Tags: uwp

Is there any way, in a UWP app, to remove the horrible gap between the titlebar buttons (minimize, maximize and close) and the content? This gap is particularly evident when using a TabView. The Terminal app seems to have solved this, and the new Chromium-Edge app as well.

[image]

Comment: Do the following works and do you have any updates?

Comment: It could perhaps solve the problem, but I have not tried since it would force me to rewrite the titlebar entirely, which I am not really ready to do yet. I wish this issue was resolved for the entirety of UWP/XAML since it looks really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way, in a UWP app, to remove the horrible gap between the titlebar buttons (minimize, maximize and close) and the content?

Sure, UWP app support `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar`, you could use the following code the extend View into `TitleBar`. And the title bar support more customization, for more info please refer [**Title bar customization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar) document.

```
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```